# tensorflow AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I try to [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)

I try to load a tfrecords dataset that I created. But I always get this Error.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_filename = ['rain.tfrecords']
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_filename)
#dataset = dataset.map(...)
dataset = dataset.repeat(EPOCHS)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

next_images, next_labels = iterator.get_next()

loss = tf.add(1,next_labels)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for step in xrange(10):
        curr_loss= sess.run(loss)
```

But tf.data... should exist?
Thank you

Comment: If you called a file `tensorflow.py`, call it something else.

Comment: No file has this name. I checked it.

Comment: Can you try adding the statement `print(dir(tf))` immediately after `import tensorflow as tf` and tell us what it prints?

Comment: <pre>['AggregationMethod', 'Assert', 'AttrValue', 'COMPILER_VERSION', 'ConditionalAccumulator', 'ConditionalAccumulatorBase', 'ConfigProto', 'DType', 'DeviceSpec', 'Dimension', 'Event', 'FIFOQueue', 'FixedLenFeature', 'FixedLenSequenceFeature', 'FixedLengthRecordReader', 'GIT_VERSION', 'GPUOptions', 'GRAPH_DEF_VERSION', ....]<code>

And a lot more, but I cant write so many characters here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running an older version of tensorflow. Try updating it to 1.4, which has the data API.

Comment: thank you, that was right
to get the actual version:
Run:
`python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 2`


`python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3`