# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'data' (TensorFlow 2.13)

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm getting environmental issues.  This code used to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Xids, Xmask, labels))
```

Now it throws errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 2
      1 #dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Xids, Xmask, labels))
----> 2 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Xids, Xmask, labels))
      4 dataset.take(1)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'data'
```

I'm running:
`tensorflow                2.13.0`

Which is pretty close to the newest version of 2.14 so I don't think that's it.

Any ideas?

**Things I've tried (besides ChatGPT):**

I saw some threads with this issue back in 2017 and was a problem with version 1.4.0.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/data/README.md

This thread from 6 years ago:
[tensorflow AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143289/tensorflow-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-data)

And this thread from a year ago but my version is July 2013.
[AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73674129/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-data)

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data?_gl=1*1ttvhv6*_ga*MjA4MjQxMDgwMi4xNjg0NDAzMDcx*_ga_W0YLR4190T*MTcwMDAwNTQ1NS42LjEuMTcwMDAwNTUyMy4wLjAuMA.. see the implementation here